# Service startup time with Thread.join

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, junit, spring-test

I have a Spring Boot service like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyService implements CommandLineRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(MyService.class);
         application.run(args);
    }

    public void run(String.... args) {
         // Spawn several non-Daemon never-ending working threads and start them (This is by design. These two threads never exit.)
         // Thread thread1 = ....
         // Thread thread2 = ....
         
         thread1.join();   
         thread2.join();
    }

    .....
}
```

In IntelliJ, the service is only marked as "started" after a very long delay (5 minutes or so). By removing the two joins, the service still works and the start-up time is reduced to a couple of seconds.

I have a SpringBootTest integration test of this service like this:

```
@SpringBootTest
public class MyServiceTest {
    @Test
    public void test() {
         System.out.println("Test started ...."):
    }
}
```

With the two join statements, this test hangs and the System.out.println call is never run. With the two joins removed, it works fine.

I think the two joins are unnecessary but I could not understand:

1. Why does my integration test hangs forever?
2. Why the spring service does not hang forever in IntelliJ, like the test.

Comment: Sure that `thread1` and `thread2` are never-ending?

Comment: When your tests hangs, try to figure out what is happening with t1 and t2. You can create a thread dump, or you can just put some breakpoints in those threads and introspect what they're doing and why they dont finish their tasks.

Comment: @dan1st Yes. thread1 and thread2 have dead loop that keep polling a message queue (I know this is a bad design but it is someone else's code I can't change).

Comment: @aleshka-batman thread1 and thread2 have dead-loop in them. They are meant to run forever and never exit.

Comment: @ZZZ so you answered you question, why test hangs forever. I can suggest you to extract your CommandLineRunner in another class and not include in Spring test application context.

Comment: @aleshka-batman But by removing the two joins, my test does not hang anymore and it works fine. I want to know what the two joins do there.

Comment: The tests are executed after the `run` method finishes (I think). `.join()` waits until a thread terminates.